# how to align slide shpw images to center inside div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted a slide show in my web page, for this I used this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:350px;

}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}
</style>
<script>
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slideshow" align="middle">
    <img src="img/11.jpg" alt="" class="active"  />
    <img src="img/12.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="img/13.jpg.jpg" alt=""  />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It is coming left of my screen. But I wanted it to come in center of my webpage.

Can anyone please tell me how to do it?

Thanks,
Regards,
Sabyasachi

Answer (score 0):

It should be `align="center"`, but even that's incorrect. You should be using CSS for that sort of thign, not deprecated tag attributes:

```
#slideshow {
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `align` attribute of `<div>` is deprecated.

Consider using `<div style="text-align:center">`, or failing that, use a `<center>` tag around the `<div>` tag.

Notwithstanding, the correct `align` attribute would be `"center"` not `"middle"`.

Answer (score 0):

The slideshow doesen't seem to work for me, but for simple center alignment, you'll need a width on your slideshow and then just margin: 0 auto; - auto on left and right are what does the trick here.

Like so:

```
#slideshow {
position:relative;
height:350px;
width:350px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

you can ditch the align="middle" in the html.

Answer (score 0):

made some changes in **#slideshow** and **#slideshow IMG** 
and i think don't use **align** in a div, vs shows a warning align attribute is outdated

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:350px;
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;

    z-index:8;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}
</style>
<script>
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="img/11.jpg" alt="" class="active"  />
    <img src="img/12.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="img/13.jpg.jpg" alt=""  />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```